# Stack build hangs on GHC-8.6.4/Cabal-2.4.1.0 on Windows

Tags: windows, haskell, dependencies, haskell-stack

My stack project build hangs on windows at the step related to Cabal.

See output below

```
C:\haskell\hrt\Comonad>stack ghc -- --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.6.4

C:\haskell\hrt\Comonad>stack build
←[0mCabal-2.4.1.0: configure←[0m
←[0mCabal-2.4.1.0: build←[0m
Progress 0/5
```

I have to interrupt with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

I've tried to follow the Haskell Weekly [Comonadic builders by Dmitrii Kovanikov](https://chshersh.github.io/posts/2019-03-25-comonadic-builders) and I've started by creating a new project

```
stack new Comonad
cd Comonad
```

then I've pasted the [code sample](https://gist.github.com/ChShersh/5a4c8e1c0557627859fe93ad0b05dd56) into the Main

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards   #-}

module Main where

import Control.Comonad (Comonad (..), (=>>))
import Data.Semigroup (Any (..))
import Data.Text (Text)
import Text.Pretty.Simple (pPrint)

import Lib
-- see the gist above for the rest of the code
alwaysTravisB :: ProjectBuilder -> Project
alwaysTravisB builder = builder $ mempty { settingsTravis = Any True }

travisB :: ProjectBuilder -> Project
travisB builder =
  let project = extract builder
  in project { projectTravis = projectGitHub project }



main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- plain
    pPrint $ extract $ buildProject "minimal-project"
    pPrint $ extract $ buildProject "only-library" =>> hasLibraryB
    pPrint $ extract $ buildProject "library-github" =>> hasLibraryB =>> gitHubB

    -- dependent: 1 level
    pPrint $ extract $ buildProject "travis" =>> travisB
    pPrint $ extract $ buildProject "always-travis" =>> alwaysTravisB
    pPrint $ extract $ buildProject "github-travis" =>> gitHubB =>> travisB
    pPrint $ extract $ buildProject "travis-github" =>> travisB =>> gitHubB
    someFunc
```

and I've specified the dependencies in the package.yaml

```
dependencies:
- base >= 4.12.0.0
- comonad >= 5.0
- pretty-simple >= 2.2
- text

library:
  source-dirs: src

executables:
  Comonad-exe:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - Comonad
```

I can see that `ghc.exe` is working on a temp folder (`C:\Users\MyHome\AppData\Local\Temp\stacknnnn`) and keep the cpu busy, I'm aso wondering if it's a memory leak (1.7GB of working set)...

[image]

```
stack build --verbose
-- ... ...
←[90m2019-04-07 11:35:28.096702: ←[32m[debug] ←[0mEncoding C:\Users\MyHome\AppData\Local\Temp\stack6060\Cabal-2.4.1.0\.s
tack-work\dist\e626a42b\stack-config-cache←[90m
@(src/Stack\Build\Cache.hs:164:7)←[0m
←[90m2019-04-07 11:35:28.098702: ←[32m[debug] ←[0mFinished writing C:\Users\MyHome\AppData\Local\Temp\stack6060\Cabal-2.
4.1.0\.stack-work\dist\e626a42b\stack-config-cache←[90m
@(src/Stack\Build\Cache.hs:164:7)←[0m
←[90m2019-04-07 11:35:28.099702: ←[32m[debug] ←[0mEncoding C:\Users\MyHome\AppData\Local\Temp\stack6060\Cabal-2.4.1.0\.s
tack-work\dist\e626a42b\stack-cabal-mod←[90m
@(src/Stack\Build\Cache.hs:173:7)←[0m
←[90m2019-04-07 11:35:28.320715: ←[32m[debug] ←[0mFinished writing C:\Users\MyHome\AppData\Local\Temp\stack6060\Cabal-2.
4.1.0\.stack-work\dist\e626a42b\stack-cabal-mod←[90m
@(src/Stack\Build\Cache.hs:173:7)←[0m
←[90m2019-04-07 11:35:28.320715: ←[34m[info] ←[0mCabal-2.4.1.0: build←[90m
@(src/Stack\Build\Execute.hs:873:23)←[0m
←[90m2019-04-07 11:35:28.322715: ←[32m[debug] ←[0mRun process within C:\Users\MyHome\AppData\Local\Temp\stack6060\Cabal-
2.4.1.0\: C:\sr\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.4.exe --builddir=.stack-work\dist\e
626a42b build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file -fdiagnostics-color=always"←[90m
@(src/Stack\Build\Execute.hs:1133:29)←[0m
Progress 0/5
-- hangs here
```

Comment: how long have you tried letting in execute? old CPU?

Comment: several minutes... I don't think it's going to do it (but I can be wrong of course). The problem is simply with the package comonad: this seems to fail `stack ghci --package comonad` inside the new project

Comment: After more than 15 minutes of CPU time it's at 2.4 GB of working set memory... does it make sense to let it execute for more time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try rerunning with `--interleaved-output`, which will show the output of each module being compiled by GHC (you may need to upgrade Stack first via `stack upgrade`). Cabal takes a *long* time to compile, it's probably just working through all the modules.

Comment: Yes, I needed to `stack upgrade` ==> `Current Stack version: 1.7.1, available download version: 1.9.3` I'm running the build with `--interleaved-output` and I'll let you know

Comment: Yeah... it took 20 minutes and more than 2.5GB for Cabal